# In Python 3.x, is it possible to check web URL for dynamic changes involving an edit date?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in the process of creating a Python script to collect CSV data from a web URL. I've had no issue setting this up with:

```
request.urlretrieve("www.RandomWebsiteInfo.com", "my output info")
```

However, one of the web URLs I wish to retrieve includes an edit date in the naming convention. Example:

ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/csvfiles/StormEvents_details-ftp_v1.0_d2018_c20180418.csv.gz

The portion of the string with "_c20180418" represents the edit date that the file was last updated. Since this constantly updates, and happens at random intervals, is there a way for Python to search within these URL strings and create and/or recognize and/or match an updated "_cYYYYMMDD" string?

I feel like, worst case scenario, I could create a looping mechanism that would try each date between the last edit and the current date until the request.urlretrieve locates a URL string that doesn't fail. I'm just not sure if that is the best practice for the task I'm attempting to accomplish. Before I try that approach, I thought I'd ask the community for any insight. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not just get the directory index?

Comment: Yea since this is on their ftp server you should be able to list all the files in that directory. Then you could get the latest or get the one that starts with `StormEvents` or however you wanted to do it

Comment: NOAA's indexing looks pretty stable, so this sounds like a good alternative. Thank you both for pointing this option out to me.